# Matching file path using awk from a report

Tags: awk, sed

Despite many attempts, I'm not able to get a proper way to extract file names from a report using awk.

I have an output like this.

```
found in file /home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/cur/1580910042.2931_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa/PURCHASE ORDER KALI-1374Wpdf.gz/PURCHASE ORDER KALI-1374Wpdf.exe/FILE:0000
found in file /home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/cur/1580910052.2932_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa/PURCHASE ORDER KALI-1374Bpdf.gz/PURCHASE ORDER KALI-1374Bpdf.exe
found in file /home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/.afolder/cur/1580910152.2935_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa/PURCHASE ORDER KALI-1364Cpdf.gz/PURCHASE ORDER KALI-1374Dpdf.exe
```

I need to extract the actual file path. Here, the actual file path is

```
/home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/.afolder/cur/1580910152.2935_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa
```

for the first line. How can I extract the actual file path from this result using awk, sed or any command using regex?

The expected output will be

```
/home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/cur/1580910042.2931_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa
/home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/cur/1580910052.2932_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa
/home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/.afolder/cur/1580910152.2935_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know that you have tried attempts, its always recommend to add them in format of code also in your questions, as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/\/[^,]*,[a-zA-Z]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/\/[^,]*,[a-zA-Z]+/){       ##Using match function of awk to match regex \/[^,]*,[a-zA-Z]+ which means match till comma then till alphabets in lines.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##Printing sub-string whose starting point is RSTART and ending point is RLENGTH.
}
'  Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` also offer a fairly easy solution by using a capture group to capture the text between the first `'/'` and the `",Sa"`, e.g.

```
$ sed 's|^[^/]*\(/.*,Sa\)/.*$|\1|' file
/home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/cur/1580910042.2931_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa
/home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/cur/1580910052.2932_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa
/home/cloudst/homes/james/Maildir/.afolder/cur/1580910152.2935_0.s3.mydomain.com:2,Sa
```

Alternate delimiters of `'|'` are used instead of `'/'` to avoid the picket-fence effect of `\/..\/.`